# Is possible to create an action for google home that take the data from a camera and use these data to process images like object recognition?

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I need to know if it's possible to create an action for google home that allows you to take the video streaming data of a camera.

I would like to be able to use this data to apply algorithms that can modify or capture data from images such as object recognition or facel recognition.

Answer (score 0):

I know you could do such actions through home assistant. Maybe pull your cams into there and push any google specific actions to your google home gear?